# Get variable value by finding keyword in unix environment

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In UNIX environment, I have a file.txt that contains following details:

```
Data recording started:
0001100 Matched at 412090
0001101 Mismatched at 414798
0001102 Matched at 420007
0001103 Mismatched at 420015
Job completed
```

How do I can get the first Matched value by searching "Matched" (line 2) word and also for the first "Mismatched" (line 3)
Find the difference between them and store as a variable, "dif" 
The result is Matched minus Mismatched, so it cannot find the data by specify line number, i.e. find line 3 last integers minus line 2 last integers, because the mismatched may come at first like following:

```
Data recording started:
0001100 Mismatched at 412090
0001101 Matched at 414798
0001102 Mismatched at 420007
0001103 Matched at 420015
Job completed
```

Comment: Do you want to do this specifically in bash (as opposed to python or awk or ruby or perl)? If so, you should mention that in the question title or in the body text, not just in the question tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
echo $(( 
      $(grep Matched input | head -1 | sed 's/.*at //') 
    - $(grep Mismatched input | head -1 | sed 's/.*at //') 
))
```

or using only sed:

```
echo $(( 
      $(sed -n 's/.*Matched.*at //p' input | head -1) 
    - $(sed -n 's/.*Mismatched.*at //p' input | head -1) 
))
```

**Output**

```
-2708
```

Comment: may I knw what is the function of 's/.*at //' ?
and how to grep the word since i saw the command didnt specify 'file.txt'?

Comment: `input` is the name of the input file. `s/.*at //` turns `0001100 Matched at 412090` into `412090`

Comment: What if there is some words after the numbers?
`0001100 Matched at 412090 line 0`
Can I still use s/.*at // ?

Comment: no, then you'll need, for example, `sed -n 's/.*Matched.*at \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' input`

Answer (score 0):

We can use grep -m 1 to kick away head.

```
dif=$(( 
      $(grep -m 1 'Matched' a.txt | sed 's/.*at \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
    - $(grep -m 1 'Mismatched' a.txt | sed 's/.*at \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
))
echo $dif
```